# Is it possible to dock the annotation layers window?

Tags: annotation

I was hoping that it's possible to dock the layers menu somehow. I use the annotate tool quite a lot; drawing where I'm going to place vertices and then build as I'm going.

I use layers for this, different colours for different parts. It's quite frustrating that accessing the layers window requires being in the annotate tool though, rather than being able to switch different layers on and off while modelling.

Anyone know a workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Annotation layers can also be found in the *View* Panel in the Right hand side panels. (Toggle with <kbd>N</kbd>)

You don't need to be using the *Annotate* tool to access it.

To keep it in place, right click on the sub-panel header and choose *Pin*. You can also use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + Left Mouse. Notice the Pin icon in the top right.

Click and drag the 8 dots in the top right of the sub-panel to rearrange it on top of all the others. That way it's always on top of whatever Panel you are in.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.